# Asp.Net Login control (Visual Web Dev)

Tags: asp.net

This is the code when you take the Login control from the toolbox.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" 
            BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                    style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                        Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                            ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                            ValidationGroup="Login1" onclick="LoginButton_Click" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </asp:Login>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Part of my aspx.cs

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sUserName = UserName.Text;
    String sPassword = Password.Text;
```

Error   1   The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context
Error   2   The name 'Password' does not exist in the current context
Error   3   'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Login1_Authenticate' and no extension method 'Login1_Authenticate' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting of your code. It doesn't fit in the area on screen and as such wraps impossibly badly.

Comment: It's ok I've fixed it.

        String sUserName = Login1.UserName;
        String sPassword = Login1.Password;

Answer (score 1):

Error 1&2 -- Shouldn't you qualify the fields you need such as UserName, by say Login1.UserName instead? (I didn't check it but that sounds right to me from memory)

Error 3 -- You do need to handle the authentication event. The control is a nice shortcut, but it doesn't actually implement any business logic or do the actual logic. So you need to do this in the code behind. -- FYI that means you probably need to type out the method definition yourself in the code behind file.